# Displaying an image from a href

Tags: java, php, jquery, html

```
<a href="image.jpg">image.jpg</a>
```

There is a load of lines like this with different pictures. 
What i need to do is to make a script of some sort that would allow displaying those images without the need to write anything new in the body (it has to find the files from href's and display them ... without causing any more work for a person who puts those pictures there) and without the need to reorganize files (those files are tied to many other things ... change in the directory = everything crashes)
but i cant just find much ... most of the scripts i find requires me to place files in a specific folder or even worse ... to make img src tags for them

Can anyone point me towards some solution here ?

Comment: I'm confused a bit. Are the images in a bunch of different directories or one directory?

Comment: how your html file getting generated with above line? Is it hard coded .html page or getting generated from server (.jsp, servlet etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on the question, but if I decipher it correctly a possible solution is to user `scandir` to read the contents of a directory. Likely will need to modify inside the `foreach` loop to fit your design (not sure if you have embedded script or not) but this will dynamically fetch and display images inside a directory.

```
if ($images = scandir('path_to_your_image_directory')) {
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        print '<a href="$image">$image.jpg</a>'; // Might need to preface the $image variable with path to your image directory
    }
}
```